# Databinding with Ajaxcontroltoolkit Accordion in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How can i Bind data in Accordian in C# .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the property `DataSource`  and set it to your Item List which you want to bind.

After that you need to call `DataBind()` have a look at [Accordion Sample for Ajax Toolkit](http://www.biberoglu.net/Accordion/Accordion.aspx)

> - DataSource - The data source to use.
> - DataBind() must be called.
> - DataSourceID - The ID of the data
>     source to use. DataMember - The member
>     to bind to when using a DataSourceID

And here is an example

```
private void BindAccordion() 
{ 
  sql = "Select distinct Cus_Type from Customers"; 
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, “YourConnectionString”); 
  DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
  da.Fill(dt); 

  Accordion1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView; 
  Accordion1.DataBind(); 
}
```

From [Simple Parent-Child data binding using Accordion](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Easy_Data_Binding_Accordion_GridView.aspx)

Comment: Actually I hav use <contentTemplate> in HTML but it didnt work.

Comment: The content template is what is used when you Bind something, see the link I provided, you will have an answer there! Follow their example and you should be good to go.